# Trying to create a 3rd person controller in Unity but the player is not moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is what I have so far.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    CharacterController control;

    [SerializeField]
    float moveSpeed = 5.0f;

    [SerializeField]
    float jumpSpeed = 20.0f;

    [SerializeField]
    float gravity = 1.0f;

    float yVelocity = 0.0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        control = GetComponent<CharacterController> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        Vector3 direction = new Vector3 (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis ("Vertical"));
        Vector3 velocity = direction * moveSpeed;

        if (control.isGrounded) {
            if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump")) {
                yVelocity += jumpSpeed;
            }
        } else {
            yVelocity -= gravity;
        }

        velocity.y = yVelocity;

        control.Move (velocity*Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I'm following a tutorial, and it looks like everything is the same, but the player is not moving.

Comment: What do you have this script attached to? Do you maybe have `moveSpeed` set to `0`?

Answer (score 0):

If it is all same with tutorial, your problem must be about your input settings. Check your "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Jump" from  Edit -> Project Settings -> Input

Then on inspector look at variables under Axis list to check them if they assigned true, maybe there is no Horizontal or Vertical variable.